# Solidity: How to represent bytes32 as string

Tags: solidity, string, bytes, bytes32

This may be simple in other languages but I can't figure out how to do it in Solidity.
I have a `bytes32` like this `0x05416460deb76d57af601be17e777b93592d8d4d4a4096c57876a91c84f4a712`.

I don't want to convert the bytes to a string, rather I just want to represent the whole thing as a string, like "0x05416460deb76d57af601be17e777b93592d8d4d4a4096c57876a91c84f4a712".
How can this be done in Solidity?

Answer (score 1):

You have to individually get the `bytes` from `bytes32`. Each `byte` represents `two` numbers from hex value. You can individually map the numbers from hex value to corresponding `char` value in the ASCII table. An example implementation is demonstrated below.

```
function bytes32ToLiteralString(bytes32 data) 
    public
    pure
    returns (string memory result) 
{
    bytes memory temp = new bytes(65);
    uint256 count;

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        bytes1 currentByte = bytes1(data << (i * 8));
        
        uint8 c1 = uint8(
            bytes1((currentByte << 4) >> 4)
        );
        
        uint8 c2 = uint8(
            bytes1((currentByte >> 4))
        );
    
        if (c2 >= 0 && c2 <= 9) temp[++count] = bytes1(c2 + 48);
        else temp[++count] = bytes1(c2 + 87);
        
        if (c1 >= 0 && c1 <= 9) temp[++count] = bytes1(c1 + 48);
        else temp[++count] = bytes1(c1 + 87);
    }
    
    result = string(temp);
}
```

For upper-case hex letters, use `55` instead of `87`.